# Visual Studio: testing on different a server than developing on

Tags: visual-studio

In dreamweaver, it's really simple to set up a site so when you test a page that you are developing that it deploys it to a different test server that you are developing on and then browses to that page at that location also.

Question:  Can you set up Visual Studio so that when you "run" or "View in Browser" that it automatically pushes the pages out to the test server and then browses to that location as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two options as far as I can see:

1) Create a local project and set it up to run from your own local IIS, (this is not exactly what you're asking, but it should be more of an apples to apples test, as opposed to the built-in visual studio web server).

2) Use Remote Debugging to attach your Visual Studio instance to a remote server, links [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227556.aspx)

With option two, you'll still likely need to publish/deploy your solution to the server each time, but you will be able to step through and debug your code running on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an FTP project (File>Open Web Site and then select FTP) - as far as I'm aware, when you *save* a file it's automatically uploaded to the specified server. Then you could just point your browser at that web server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible,but you can always set up a shared folder where you put your code, and that shared folder is in fact the folder where your web server expect the code to be.